django-elasticsearch-dsl ManyToMany NestedField 10000 limit issue
I am using the django-elasticsearch-dsl package to save models in Elasticsearch for searching, but I am encountering an issue. It saves the Foreign Key relations as nested documents, and Elasticsearch has a limit of 10,000 nested documents, causing an error when indexing the document.
Although we can increase the nested documents limit, it is not a good idea.
Code sample:
# models.py
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    color = models.CharField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    created = models.DateField()

class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', related_name='ads')

# documents.py
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields
from .models import Car, Manufacturer, Ad

@registry.register_document
class CarDocument(Document):
    manufacturer = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'name': fields.TextField(),
        'country_code': fields.TextField(),
    })
    ads = fields.NestedField(properties={
        'description': fields.TextField(analyzer=html_strip),
        'title': fields.TextField(),
        'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'cars'

    class Django:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'name',
            'color',
        ]
        related_models = [Manufacturer, Ad]  # Optional: to ensure the Car will be re-saved when Manufacturer or Ad is updated

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Not mandatory but to improve performance we can select related in one sql request"""
        return super(CarDocument, self).get_queryset().select_related(
            'manufacturer'
        )

    def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
        if isinstance(related_instance, Manufacturer):
            return related_instance.car_set.all()
        elif isinstance(related_instance, Ad):
            return related_instance.car

Error:
'error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'The number of nested documents has exceeded the allowed limit of [10000]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.mapping.nested_objects.limit] index level setting.'},

Any insights or guidance you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
I tried the examples provided in the documentation, checked all open and closed issues on the project's GitHub, and searched on Stack Overflow for a solution.
I am looking for a way to save the related data into separate indexes. For example, the Car should be in a separate index, and ads should be saved in another separate index to avoid the issue of nested documents.
